# How can I develop my own /env endpoint in Spring Boot without remove Actuator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot application (Java 8, Spring Boot 1.5.9) with Actuator, but I need to write my own response for the `/env` endpoint. I tried disabling it with the property `endpoints.env.enabled=false` but the response that I get is an `HTTP 500` instead of an `HTTP 404`.

Is there any way to write my own `/env` endpoint without remove all the Actuator library of the project?

Comment: Yes, override the `/env` actuator.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do this in two steps:

First, re-map the `/env` path to something else in the `application.properties` file, e.g:

```
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.env=default-env
```

Second, write our own endpoint implementation for the `/env` endpoint, e.g

```
@RestController
public class EnvController {
    @GetMapping(value="/actuator/env")
    public ResponseEntity<String> env() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("My custom env endpoint");
    }
}
```